# When is an edit of a question visible to other users when it requires a peer review?

Tags: discussion, review, edits

I have edited a question, and i got this message:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

I then click on peer reviewed link and i can see:

> Your suggested edit is pending review.
>   userXYZ reviewed this 3 hours ago: Approve

I take it my edit has been reviewed by that user and has been approved, right? does it have to be peer-reviewed by more users?

**Edit:**

I disagree with the "duplicate question" mark given. the question suggested is much more general and does not address my question specifically, This question is much more similar to the one linked on the accepted answer below, but finding that question could prove difficult given its Title is "*It takes two to tango?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit is not publicly viewable to all users before it's approved. Approval or rejection is the result of **Reviewing**. What you've seen is the **Review Queue**. Review Queue is intended for trusted users to audit these kinds of suggested edits (and other kinds of audits), and is available only for users with [sufficient reputation](/help/privileges/edit). After 2 people agreed that your edit is constructive ([3 on SO](/a/151586)), it will finally become visible to everyone else and remain as a "revision" to the post.

As you're the promoter of an suggested edit, Stack Exchange is designed to allow you to view the revision state of your suggestion. You won't see any other things in the Review Queue, however.

Comment: thanks, that solves my question, although you say it needs 3 on SO and in the same link you provided, there is an update to the answer where they state that the number of reviews needed has been dropped to the network wide 2.